# How to brush with pencil via d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot

I would like to be able to select data in the scatterplot with pencil via d3js library.

I have found following sample - https://jsfiddle.net/3mjduntb/ - but there is possible to brush only with rectangle.

Source: https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/interactivity_brush.html

I can see the API for brushing:

```
 // Add brushing
  svg
    .call( d3.brush()                 // Add the brush feature using the d3.brush function
      .extent( [ [0,0], [width,height] ] ) // initialise the brush area: start at 0,0 and finishes at width,height: it means I select the whole graph area
      .on("start brush", updateChart) // Each time the brush selection changes, trigger the 'updateChart' function
    )
```

I cannot find any way how to modify this selection method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this plugin which is exactly what I needed:

https://bl.ocks.org/skokenes/a85800be6d89c76c1ca98493ae777572

It is lasso plugin in d3.js plugins.